# Can I transfer EOS from one account to other using eosjs or is EOS only used for buying RAM and staking? (Both accounts are on jungle testnet)

Tags: transactions, eosjs

```
async function sendEos (sender, receiver ) {
 try{
const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio.token',      //'eosio.token',
      name: 'transfer',                //'transfer',
      authorization: [{
        actor: sender, //'useraaaaaaaa',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        from: sender,
        to: receiver,
        quantity: '1 EOS',
        memo: '',
      },
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.dir(result);
}catch (e) {
console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + e);
if (e instanceof RpcError)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2))}};
```

Getting error:

```
Caught exception: Error: assertion failure with message: symbol precision mismatch (node:12620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: RpcError is not defined
at sendEos (E:\EOSIO\transactEos.js:45:22)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

What fields do I need to change? I hope someone can guide me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EOS precision you have provided here is `1 EOS` and that is your error. The typical precision is `1.0000 EOS`. If you also want your transaction to be signed and broadcasted to the network:

```
async function sendEos (sender, receiver ) {
 try{
const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio.token',      //'eosio.token',
      name: 'transfer',                //'transfer',
      authorization: [{
        actor: sender, //'useraaaaaaaa',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        from: sender,
        to: receiver,
        quantity: '1.0000 EOS',
        memo: '',
      },
    }]
  }, {
    sign: true,
    broadcast: true,
    keyProvider: 'Your private key here',
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.dir(result);
}catch (e) {
console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + e);
if (e instanceof RpcError)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2))}};
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to do anything else for transaction to be broadcasted to the network?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to